# Sitecore @Html.Sitecore.Field is not rendering any values

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

In the below code model, fields are returning values, but when I try to render using `@Html.Sitecore().Field` it returns `null`. I would like those fields to be editable in the Experience Editor. How can I achieve this?

It is a controller rendering with a specified data source.

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@using Sitecore.Data

@model Project.Service.Models.Model
<div>
<h1>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Property Name")</h1>
<!--- Main header --->
<h4 class="text-danger"><em>
<span itemprop="streetAddress"> @Model.ProvinceName</span>,
<span itemprop="addressLocality">@Model.CityName</span>,
<span itemprop="addressRegion">@Model.ProvinceName</span> 
 @Model.PostalCode</em></h4>
```

I am new to Sitecore and any help or suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.Sitecore().Field("Property Name")` only works when your model is `Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel`. You are using a custom model.

To use it in your case, you will need to pass in the item like this:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Property Name", Item)
```

OR

you can also inherit `IRenderingModel` to your present model something like this

```
Model: IRenderingModel
```

If your model inherits `IRenderingModel` than your code will look like this:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Property Name")
```

Please rate this answer up if this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to render the "Property Name" field from the context item. It probably doesn't have one. You'll need to tell your model what Item you're referencing and render it with something like `@Html.Sitecore().Field("Property Name", Model.Item)`